# Emulate CMD in Metro Style App For Win 8 on ARM

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

As we know , we are not going to have a command line prompt as we in traditional Windows system for Windows on ARM.
      I am trying to emulate command line prompt. The Question i have is it possible for us to spawn new process/app from a given app (as a background task could also do) with parent app having all information about child app?

Comment: Many things a Metro app can't do.  This is all you got: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You CAN dynamically load and execute assemblies.
Assembly.Load() works fine - as long as the target is a System assembly or in your app's package graph (i.e. in your app's package, or a declared 's package).

You're right, Metro/Desktop are very different. A 'MetroCMD.exe' would by definition be restricted; given the isolated nature of Metro apps, would a Metro CMD.EXE be useful?